# Sha1_file function not working for me

Tags: php, database, sha1

```
function addFlyer($db){
if (isset($_FILES['file_array'])) {
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++) {
        if (file_exists('images/' . sha1_file($name_array[$i]))) {
            // File exists already in the folder.
            $uploadOk = 0;
            header("Location: admin.php?action=errorupload");   
        }

        else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "images/" . sha1_file($name_array[$i]))) {
                //upload complete
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                //upload failed.
                header("Location: admin.php?action=errorupload");
            }
        }
}

    if($uploadOk == 1 && isset($_POST['month'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_POST['content1'], $_POST['content2'])) {
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO version (month, title, content, content1, content2, imgurls, imgurlm, imgurll, imgurlfb) VALUES(:month, :title, :content, :content1, :content2, :imgurls, :imgurlm, :imgurll, :imgurlfb)");
        $query->bindParam(':month', $_POST['month'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':content', $_POST['content'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':content1', $_POST['content1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':content2', $_POST['content2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':imgurls', sha1_file($_FILES['file_array']['name'][0]), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':imgurlm', sha1_file($_FILES['file_array']['name'][1]), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':imgurll', sha1_file($_FILES['file_array']['name'][2]), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':imgurlfb', sha1_file($_FILES['file_array']['name'][3]), PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $query->execute();
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }
```

}
}

Currently I got this code, but it isn't hashing the files and it won't put it in the database. What is going wrong right now? It just goes to the error page I made, someone knows a solution?

Comment: You’ll need to do some basic debugging …

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't work.

```
$name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
...
if (file_exists('images/' . sha1_file($name_array[$i]))) {
```

As you can learn from the PHP documentation about the [file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php),
`$_FILES['...']['name']` is:

> The original name of the file on the **client machine**.

And you pass that name to `sha1_file()` and expect it to find the file on **your server** and process it.

If you want to store each file only once and do that by naming the file with the SHA1 of its content then you should SHA1 the content, which is on your server, waiting to be processed, in `$_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name']`. Or `$tmp_name_array` if you prefer it this way.

And you should call `sha1_file()` only once for each file and not twice, as it is a time consuming operation.

Try this (I changed only the lines that contain `$local_file_name`):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++) {
    $local_file_name = sha1_file($tmp_name_array[$i]);
    if (file_exists('images/'.$local_file_name)) {
        // File exists already in the folder.
        $uploadOk = 0;
        header("Location: admin.php?action=errorupload");   
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], 'images/'.$local_file_name)) {
            //upload complete
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            //upload failed.
            header("Location: admin.php?action=errorupload");
        }
    }
}
```